# Save a ListView layout on Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` containing news from RSS feeds in `MainActivity`, the problem is I have to stream the RSS feeds everytime I open the app because the items of the `ListView` are destroyed when I close the app.

I understand I can save it in SQLite temporarily, but is there a more simple way to save the ListView layout just so it would still be there next time I open the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use SharePreferences and Gson to convert your datasource for the list view into a string for storage and then when the app is re-opened you can rebuild the list view with the stored data fairly quickly. I do something similar in one app where the data source for my list view is a ArrayList of LinkedHashMap items, so this would be the two methods for converting the ArrayList to a String and then back to an ArrayList when needed

```
public static String ArrayListToString(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> list) {
    return gson.toJson(list);
}

public static ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> StringToArrayList(String input) {
    Type collectiontype = new TypeToken<ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>>(){}.getType();
    ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> list = gson.fromJson(input, collectiontype );
    return list;
}
```

I would also then suggest storing a timestamp so you can check if the stored list should be displayed or if an updated list needs to be retrieved

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.clientListView)
    ...whatever other setup you want to do here
    CheckTimeStamp();
    }

      public static void CheckTimeStamp() {
    String timeStamp = preferences.getString("keyClientTimeStamp", "");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    String currentTime = HelperClass.GetSimpleDateFormat(date);
    if (currentTime.equals(timeStamp)) {
        String storedString = preferences.getString("keyStoredClients", "");
        clientArrayList = HelperClass.StringToArrayList(decryptedArray);
        //the setupView method is where I take my ArrayList 
        //and add it to my ListView's Adapter
        SetupView();
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.keySalesTimeStamp, currentTime);
        editor.apply();
        //for me this is a web service that get's a list of clients, 
        //converts that list to a String to store in SharedPreferences 
        //and then calls SetupView() to add the list to the ListView Adapter
        GetClientList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would use Volley library for caching requests, I guess it very simple: you do request and next time first of all get it from cache. You don't have to explicitly save and describe a model for storing data for this case.

Below, I gave the example of how it might look:

```
public class RSSProvider {

    private final RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    // ...

    private RSSProvider(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    // ...

    public void getSomething(final Response.Listener<String> responseListener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        if (mRequestQueue.getCache().get(<URL>) != null) {
            responseListener.onResponse(new String(mRequestQueue.getCache().get(<URL>).data));
        } else {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, <URL>, responseListener, errorListener);
            request.setShouldCache(true);
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```